# What is the difference between location.host and location.hostname_?

Tags: javascript

They are returning the exact same thing currently.

Not sure why

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

does not cover this.

This [link by W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) is does not cover specifics as well.

Not sure why both sources do not cover this.

Comment: In less then 5 seconds with any search engine you prefer... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Comment: Here [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) covers `host` and `hostname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases they are the same, for example for this site `location.host` and `location.hostname` will both report stackoverflow.com.

In rare cases when a port is explicitly stated in the URL it will be appended to the `location.host`

Answer (score 2):

> They are returning the exact same thing - the protocol, domain, and path combined.

No, neither of them does. As the [MDN documentation for `Location` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) says:

> - **`host`**
>     Is a `DOMString` containing the host, that is the *hostname*, a `':'`, and the *port* of the URL.
> - **`hostname`**
>     Is a `DOMString` containing the domain of the URL.
> - **`port`**
>     Is a `DOMString` containing the port number of the URL.

On most sites you'll visit, there is no port in the URI, so they yield the same value in that case.

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.hostname` returns the domain name of the web host, whilst `window.location.host` will also include a port number if one is specified.

Answer (score 0):

in the eg: `localhost:8000` hostname gives you name "localhost" whereas host gives you "localhost:8000"